# Why is the base type of an open generic type not open?

Tags: c#, reflection

Consider a piece of the code below:

```
public class A<T> { }

public class B<T> : A<T> { }
```

In such case:

```
var a = typeof(A<>).GenericTypeArguments.Length;
```

`a` has the value `0`, which is not surprising. This, however, is somehow unexpected for me:

```
var b = typeof(B<>).BaseType.GenericTypeArguments.Length;
```

where `b` has the value `1`. So it is closed using a non-existing type of name "T" and only doing `GetGenericTypeDefinition` on it makes it open again. Why is that?

Comment: The `System.Type` class does not have a method named `GetGenericTypeArguments`. Did you mean `GetGenericArguments`?

Comment: @Wazner: yup, fixed.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/n6jJ4A - I get 0 and 1.

Comment: What's more, `Console.WriteLine(typeof(B<>).BaseType.GenericTypeArguments[0].FullName == null);` gives true.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> So it is closed using a non-existing type of name "T" and only doing GetGenericTypeArgument on it makes it open again. Why is that?

Because there *is* one type argument provided - the type parameter to `B`.

Look at how you're specifying the base class:

```
public class B<T> : A<T>
```

What's the `T` in `A<T>` if it's not a type argument? Just because the type argument is itself a type parameter doesn't mean it's not being specified as a type argument.

Consider this:

```
public class A<T1, T2> { }

public class B<T> : A<T, int> { }
```

Here, the base class of `B<T>` is `A<T, int>` - and you can determine that the `int` has been specified by asking for the type arguments. You can also show where the `T` comes from:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class A<T1, T2> { }

public class B<T> : A<T, int> { }

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var bT = typeof(B<>).GetTypeInfo().GenericTypeParameters[0];
        var listT = typeof(List<>).GetTypeInfo().GenericTypeParameters[0];
        var bBaseArguments = typeof(B<>).BaseType.GenericTypeArguments;
        Console.WriteLine(bBaseArguments[0] == bT); // True
        // Shows that the T from B<T> isn't the same as the T from List<T>
        Console.WriteLine(bBaseArguments[0] == listT); // False
        Console.WriteLine(bBaseArguments[1] == typeof(int)); // True
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly. Only thing I can add is that you can make it a generic type definition again (which implicitly also demonstrates how this works because this works :-) ). E.g.: `typeof(B<>).BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().GenericTypeArguments.Length` will give you 0 again.

Answer (score 0):

The [Type.GenericTypeArguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.generictypearguments(v=vs.110).aspx) property returns the types used as generic parameters for a closed generic type, for open generic types, it returns an emtpy array.

The reason `typeof(B<>).BaseType.GenericTypeArguments` does not return an empty array is because it's not a open generic type.

To illustrate this behaviour, I used `Type.MetadataToken` to identify types.

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(A<>).GetGenericArguments()[0].MetadataToken);
Console.WriteLine(typeof(B<>).GetGenericArguments()[0].MetadataToken);
Console.WriteLine(typeof(B<>).BaseType.GetGenericArguments()[0].MetadataToken);
```

This prints the following on the screen (numbers will vary, but equality will stay the same):

```
704643073
704643074
704643074
```

This indicates that the `BaseType` of type `B<>` is indeed a closed type having its generic parameter the 'virtual' generic type of class `A<>`.

Comment: Yup,  I'm sorry, but I have used the wrong method in my example at first. Please try the current one.

Comment: Also note that `MetadataToken` isn't good identifier when working with generics, since all of `A<T>`, `A<>` and e.g. `A<int>` will have the same value of it. Concrete generic implementations are made during runtime from the same IL entity (thus having the same token).